# how to validate date and show error when it not in the correct format

Tags: angular, angular-material, momentjs, angular-reactive-forms, angular-moment

I have a date (with momentjs). the date must be in DD/MM/YYYY format.

My hmtl code is:

```
<mat-form-field>
            <input id="datanint" formControlName="dateBirth" matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" />
            <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
            <mat-datepicker #picker startView="multi-year" [startAt]="startDate"></mat-datepicker>

        </mat-form-field>
```

My control is:

```
dateBirth: [DateValidator.validateDate],
```

this is my validator:

```
export class DateValidator implements Validators {


  static validateDate(fdValue: AbstractControl) {
regexDate="...:";
    console.log(fdValue);
   if(fdValue != null && fdValue.value!= null && fdValue.value.match(regexDate) {
     return { pattern: true };
   }
}
```

The problem is that when I put a Date like this (13/13/2000), I want that in my errors (in form control) there is the `pattern error` but it not in this way because the
`fdValue.value` is equals to null (when input value is 13/13/2000). I need that `fdValue.value` (or something that I can use to get the correct value) must be the same in input value also date doesn't in the correct format.

Answer (score 1):

In this Scenerio, you can not get value of fromControl and it will always shows you null for `console.log(fdValue.value);` Because may be you are passing some some invalid input in datepicker input.
So when you put invalid value to datepicker your `fdValue` is null but you still can get your input in `error` object

```
 static validateDate(fdValue: AbstractControl) {
    const date = fdValue.value;
    console.log('date: ',fdValue);
    console.log('error: ',fdValue.errors?.matDatepickerParse?.text);
    if (date ===null || date==='') return { requiredFromDate: true };
  
  }
```

[image]

but when you put invalid date input you will get `fdValue.value` is `null` errors objects contains that input value

[image]

For checking code please check [angular-customvalidator-by-naib](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-customvalidator-by-naib?file=app%2Fapp.validators.ts)